# emulator crashing aftert few moments

Tags: android, camera, emulation

What i am trying to do is to assign a surfaceView to the emulator's cam(I don't want to take snap shots just preview). I've given permission for cam usage in the manisfest and i gave the emulator access to my webcam. The application is great and it is doing what it is supposed to do BUT the emulator keeps crashing in 15 secs at best. MY emulator has 1.5 GB of RAM and my pc's RAM is 8 GB.

```
Camera mCamera;
SurfaceView mPreview;
ImageView myView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

    mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    //myView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myview);
    mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mCamera = Camera.open();
  // Picasso.with(this).load("").into(myView);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCamera.stopPreview();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCamera.release();
    Log.d("CAMERA","Destroy");
}

public void onCancelClick(View v) {
    finish();
}

public void onSnapClick(View v) {
   // mCamera.takePicture(this,null, null, mPicture);
    mCamera.takePicture(this, null, null, this);


}

@Override
public void onShutter() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    //Here, we chose internal storage
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("picture.jpg", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        out.write(data);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    camera.startPreview();
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);
    params.setPreviewSize(selected.width,selected.height);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mCamera.startPreview();
    //Picasso.with(this).load("").into(myView);

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
       // Picasso.with(this).load("").into(myView);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i("PREVIEW","surfaceDestroyed");
}
```

EDIT: What is frustrating is that the android monitor doesn't show anything wrong

```
10-18 15:08:15.823 2318-2318/com.example.user.tryagain I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-18 15:08:15.847 2318-2318/com.example.user.tryagain W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.tryagain-1/lib/x86
10-18 15:08:19.275 2318-2318/com.example.user.tryagain W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.tryagain-1/lib/x86
10-18 15:08:19.418 2318-2469/com.example.user.tryagain D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                     [ 10-18   15:08:19.422  2318: 2318 D/         ]
                                                                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xac42ef00, tid 2318
10-18 15:08:19.474 2318-2469/com.example.user.tryagain I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-18 15:08:19.515 2318-2469/com.example.user.tryagain W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-18 15:08:19.516 2318-2469/com.example.user.tryagain W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa4551c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-18 15:08:19.953 2318-2318/com.example.user.tryagain I/Choreographer:  Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: add error stack trace

Comment: I've added everything on the android monitor and it is not showing anything wrong